# Repository testing with mocktail and flutter test - I'm trying to write a test for my repository but I keep getting an error 'No such mrthod'

Tags: flutter, mocking, flutter-test

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc0Il.png) Repository testing with mocktail and flutter test - I'm trying to write a test for my repository but I keep getting an error 'No such method'
I've tried with ThenAnswer as well but it still won't go through. I'll appreciate any help :)
That's what my code looks like :
Test file:

```
`import 'package:curlzzz_new/data_source/remote_watch_data_source.dart';
import 'package:curlzzz_new/models/watch_model.dart';
import 'package:curlzzz_new/repositories/watch_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockWatchDataSource extends Mock implements RemoteWatchDataSource {}

void main() {
  //sut to System under testing
  late WatchRepository sut;
  late MockWatchDataSource dataSource;
  setUp(() {
    dataSource = MockWatchDataSource();
    sut = WatchRepository(dataSource);
  });
  group('getWatchStream', () {
    test('should return a stream of WatchModels', () {
      //1
      when(() => dataSource.getRemoteWatchStream()).thenThrow(
        (_) => Stream.value([
          WatchModel(title: 'titanic', id: '555'),
          WatchModel(title: 'top gun', id: '555'),
          WatchModel(title: 'matrix', id: '111')
        ]),
      );
      //2
      final results = sut.getWatchStream();
      //3
      expect(results, [
        WatchModel(title: 'titanic', id: '555'),
        WatchModel(title: 'top gun', id: '555'),
        WatchModel(title: 'matrix', id: '111')
      ]);
    });
  });
}
`
```

Repository:

```
import 'package:curlzzz_new/data_source/remote_watch_data_source.dart';
import 'package:curlzzz_new/models/watch_model.dart';

class WatchRepository {
  WatchRepository(this.remoteDataSource);
  final RemoteWatchDataSource remoteDataSource;

  Stream<List<WatchModel>> getWatchStream() {
    return remoteDataSource.getRemoteWatchStream().map((querySnapshot) {
      return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        return WatchModel(title: doc['title'], id: doc.id);
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  Future<void> addMovies({
    required String title,
  }) {
    return remoteDataSource.addRemoteWatchData(title: title);
  }

  Future<void> dismiss({required String id}) {
    return remoteDataSource.dismissRemoteData(id: id);
  }
}
```

Data Source:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class RemoteWatchDataSource {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getRemoteWatchStream() {
    final userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    if (userID == null) {
      throw Exception('User is not logged in');
    }
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userID)
        .collection('movies')
        .snapshots();
  }

  Future<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>?> addRemoteWatchData({
    required String title,
  }) async {
    final userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    if (userID == null) {
      throw Exception('User is not logged in');
    }
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userID)
        .collection('movies')
        .add(
      {'title': title},
    );
  }

  Future<void> dismissRemoteData({required String id}) async {
    final userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    if (userID == null) {
      throw Exception('User is not logged in');
    }
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userID)
        .collection(
          'movies',
        )
        .doc(id)
        .delete();
   
  }
}
```

It seems like a a problem with the closure type.

Comment: please post full error

Comment: I added a screenshot above, as an error Message

Answer (score 0):

try this. don't combine 2 functions in a single test.

```html
  group('getWatchStream', () {
    test('should return a stream of WatchModels', () async {
      final List<WatchModel> models = [
          WatchModel(title: 'titanic', id: '555'),
          WatchModel(title: 'top gun', id: '555'),
          WatchModel(title: 'matrix', id: '111')
      ];
      //1
      when(() => dataSource.getRemoteWatchStream()).thenAnswer(
        (_) => Stream.value(models),
      );
      //2
     await dataSource.getRemoteWatchStream();
      //3
      expect(dataSource.getRemoteWatchStream, emits(models)  );
    });
  });
```

Comment: Nów I'm getting an error by Stream.value(models) --> The argument type 'List<WatchModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'.

Comment: thats expected because that is what your function returns. i just passed the param that you are trying to pass. Meaning to say you still didnt understand your code well thats why you are passing the wrong data. And what i can see is your code is not yet ready for testing. Its not well refactored in a way that is testable and maintainable. So what i can say is before continuing the test, refactor your code first in a way that is neat and testable.